# Not getting PurchaseStatus.cancel notification after refund in_app_purchases via Play Store

Tags: flutter, google-play

I am using [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) plugin in flutter to handle purchases for Google Play Store for non-consumable product (premium features). I successfully purchased product with my test user (developer account)

However, when I request a refund and even if refund is already granted, I am not getting cancel notification from app in InAppPurchase.instance.purchase stream. I am totally sure I am always listening to the stream.

I even tried to purchase it again after refund to make sure the purchase refunded. I was able to purchase the second time but didn't get no cancel notification.

Could you help me on how to get cancel notification? I am not using any backend server but I know I should in future for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of now, there is no cancel purchase listening. But if product is cancelled, it will disappear from purchase list. You can cancel premium feature by checking history like this:

```
  void _checkPremiumFeature() async {
    List<GooglePlayPurchaseDetails>? history = await queryPastPurchasesForAndroid();

    if (history == null) return;

    bool purchased = false;

    // check if any past purchase
    for (var purchase in history) {
      logger.w(
          'Purchased product found in history: ${purchase.productID}, status: ${purchase.status}');

      if (purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased ||
          purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
        purchased = true;
      }
    }

    if (!purchased) {
      logger.w('No purchased products found in history');
    }

    _accessDbProvider.setPremium(purchased);
  }


 Future<List<GooglePlayPurchaseDetails>?> queryPastPurchasesForAndroid() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      try {
        final InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition androidAddition =
            _inAppPurchase.getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>();
        var response = await androidAddition.queryPastPurchases();
        logger.d('Got purchases. Count: ${response.pastPurchases.length}');
        return response.pastPurchases;
      } catch (e, st) {
        SentryManager.reportError('Error retrieving past purchases', e, st);
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception('Unsupported platform exception: ${Platform.localeName}');
    }
  }
```

Comment: what version are you using and what method are you using to retrieve past purchases? I couldnt see such method, currently using version 3.1.13 .

Comment: Sorry there was a separate method in my code. I updated the answer now. There should be similar way for iOS but didn't research as my app is for android only for now.